# Optimize iPhone App File Size with a lot of Images

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, image

I've made an "magic" app with a lot of coins/playing-cards.
Therefore I have a lot of images of coins, dollar bills, playing cards etc. (regular + retina resolution)

This results in a relative big file size of the final app, which I would like to avoid; since it can't be downloaded without a wifi-connection.

Currently it's 48.6 mb when downloading it from the App Store.

The images (100+) is all .png's saved in two versions, for the regular and retina displays.

Is there anyway to optimize this and reducing the final file size of my app?

I've considdered only storing the big (@2x) .png's and the scaling them accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had a lot of success using [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.pornel.net/) to compress the size of images in my application.

Also, if your images are png-24, you can reduce them png-8 and save a lot of space as well.  png-8 doesn't support transparency though.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up saving them as png-8

It worked okay after playing around with the transparency settings

Comment: For saving as PNG8 I recommend ImageOptim's sister app [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com), which — unlike Photoshop — can preserve alpha channel, and it has higher quality conversion than Fireworks.

Comment: thats good is there any API or library can do with xcode image optimization

Answer (score 1):

Why save 2 sizes? Do you have to display so many at a time that loading the retina version takes up too much memory on a 3G? Personally I don't think you should still think of supporting such an old device. Apple also dropped support for it a while ago and it really is lacking the memory for some decent applications.

Also, have you tried using some tools to compress your images without the users noticing it? like photoshop "save for web & devices", or yahoo's services etc.

Comment: The iPhone 3GS runs the current iOS 5, is still for sale to brand new customers, and doesn't have a Retina Display.

Comment: what does it having a retina display have to do with it all? its more about the amount of memory your app uses

Comment: I only have to display ONE image at a time.

My question is then do I need to store images for both regular and retina diplays? Eg 100 x 100px and a 50 x 50 px?

Or could I somehow just have the retina-version and then scale it down on the non-retina displays?

BTW saving them in Photoshop using "For Web and Devices" seems beeing a good idea - much better than using other png-compressing software, that I have found.

Thanks!

Comment: yeah I think you should just resize it then, UIImage makes use of CGRect which is in points, so you should actually not have to worry about the resizing at all!

Answer (score 1):

why do you need to store TWO versions of images? Just use hires imges in regular displays. Or, if you whant so, you can distribute 2 apps...
Are you shure, that your images has necessary sizes? i mean retina display has 680x920 pixels. if you are don't zooming images, you don'n need to make them bigger. And in this case, mb *.app file, in archive... there must be 1000 images...